# How to automatically satisfy dependencies in ".dsc" files while building debian package from source?

Tags: debian, dpkg

When I download some package sources, (e.g. foo-[ver].orig.tar.gz, foo-[ver].dsc), I often encounter dependencies problem while using `dpkg-source -x foo-[ver].dsc` and `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc ...`. In this case, I have to install the building dependencies one by one. Is there some tool to automatically handle this case, e.g., `dpkg-source-dependencies -x foo-[ver].dsc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pbuilder` is just the tool for this job. `pbuilder` will set up a minimal distribution in a tarball upon install. For building a `.dsc` file, you supply the file and `pbuilder` unzips the tarball, `chroot`s, installs all necessary build dependencies and compiles the package. As a result of this procedure, your build result is independent from the current configuration of the host machine.

Comment: The `pbuilder` is a little complex. I'll try it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7):

When trying to build a package the following should grab all dependencies:

`apt-get build-dep [package-name]`

Also, apt-get can compile source packages if needs be:

`apt-get --build [package-name]`

Comment: Doh!  Thanks for the edit Gus.  To this day, I still sometimes put --build-dep - old habits die hard.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to go about this (as seen from the other replies). For a package that is already part of a repository, you can simply use:

```
apt-get build-dep pkgname
```

For local packages, one of:

```
apt-get build-dep source-dir/
apt-get build-dep source-name.dsc
/usr/lib/pbuilder/pbuilder-satisfydepends* --control source-name.dsc
mk-build-deps --install source-name.dsc
pbuilder build source-name.dsc
sbuild source-name.dsc
```

There are probably other solutions, but the above are the most widely used.

Answer (score -1):

I'm extracting the Build-Depends from debian/control and afterwards install them with apt.
A few standard packages are not mentioned as Build-Depends (e.g. build-essentials) and required silently from debuild.

```
pkgs=$(grep Build-Depends debian/control|sed 's/^Build-Depends: //g)
pkgs=$(echo $pkgs|sed "s/[() ]//g"|tr "," " ")
apt-get install $pkgs build-essential
```

Comment: This doesn't work when Build-Depends are listed on several lines, and doesn't remove the `>=versionnumber` modifier.